# ZF3: Controllers with child routes doesn't work

Tags: php, model-view-controller, configuration, zend-framework3

I'm ZF2 developer and I'm migrating to ZF3 and I'm having troubles whith some controllers.

For example, I have this url: http://localhost/admin which calls to the correct controller (IndexController) and show the correct view. But If I want to associate this url: http://localhos/admin/articulo with ArticuloController doesn't work. When I call to this url: http://localhost/admin/articulo the controller called is AdminController and doesn't find the view.

**OPTION 1 => module.config.php:**

```
namespace Admin;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'admin' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/admin[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'admin/articulos' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/admin/articulos[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ArticulosController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],            
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            Controller\ArticulosController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout-admin.phtml',
            'admin/index/index'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
        /*
         * Con este array de parámetros permitimos enviar datos y no mostrar vista
         */
        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],           
    ],
];
```

**OPTION 2 => module.config.php (ZF2 style):**

```
namespace Admin;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'admin' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/admin[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'admin/articulos' => [
                'type'    => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/admin/articulos[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => 'Articulos',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],                 
                ],
                'may_terminate' =>  true,
                'child_routes'  =>  [
                    'default'   =>[
                        'type'  =>  Segment::class,
                        'options'   =>  [
                            'route' =>  '/[:controller[/:action][/:id1]]',
                            'constraints'   =>  [
                                'controller'    =>  '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'        =>  '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id1'           =>  '[0-9_-]*'
                            ],
                            'defaults'  =>  [],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],            
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            Controller\ArticulosController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout-admin.phtml',
            'admin/index/index'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
        /*
         * Con este array de parámetros permitimos enviar datos y no mostrar vista
         */
        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],           
    ],
];
```

**OPTION 3 => module.config.php (following zf3 tutorial):**
https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/routing/#http-routing-examples

```
namespace Admin;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'admin' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/admin[/:action]',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                'may_terminate' =>  true,
                'child_routes'  =>  [
                    'articulos' =>  [
                        'type'  =>  Segment::class,
                        'options'   =>  [
                            'route' =>  '/articulos[/:action]',
                            'defaults'  =>  [
                                'controller'    => Controller\ArticulosController::class,
                                'action'        =>  'index'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],           
        ],
    ],
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
            Controller\ArticulosController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => [
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout-admin.phtml',
            'admin/index/index'       => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ],
        'template_path_stack' => [
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
        /*
         * Con este array de parámetros permitimos enviar datos y no mostrar vista
         */
        'strategies' => [
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ],           
    ],
];
```

For all of the configurations when I call the url: http://localhost/admin/articulos the view that I get is ...

[image]

Where you can see that the controller called is Admin\Controller\IndexController and not Admin\Controller\ArticulosController

What am I doing wrong?

Update 1:

The option 3 configuration works fine!!! I have delete all the content from /cache directory and now the controller is found but ... I have got now an error rendering the template ...

**Message:**

> Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template
>   "admin/articulos/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file

**Stack Trace:**

> 0 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(207):
>   Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render()
>
> 1 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(236):
>   Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> 2 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/View.php(200):
>   Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> 3 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(105):
>
> Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
>
> 4 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322):
>   Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> 5 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(171):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> 6 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(367):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEvent(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> 7 /var/www/html/31juegos/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(348):
>   Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> 8 /var/www/html/31juegos/public/index.php(40): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
>
> 9 {main}

[image]

Comment: I suggest this is closed as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **typo** issue. Try with this `http://localhost/admin/articulos` (note the ending **"s"**) because your router is `/admin/articulos` which points to this `ArticulosController`'s `indexAction()`. That is why this url `http://localhost/admin/articulo` (without ending **"s"**) was not able to dispatch. And the view structure should be of type `module/controller/action`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! But with http://localhost/admin/articulos doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes. I Have added more information in my initial post

Comment: According to the configuration of your **OPTION 1** and **OPTION 3** `admin/articulos` and `admin/index/articulos` route respectively works fine here.

Comment: Please fix the view template as `admin/articulos/index.phtml` instead of `admin/articulos/index/index.phtml`

Comment: Yes!!!! I have see it right now and fix it!!! Thank you so much for your appreciated help!!! You save my life!!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Finally, I have fixed my last problem. The problem was due to my index.phtml was in an wrong directory `/view/admin/articulos/**index/**index.phtml`. The correct directory is `/view/admin/articulos/index.phtml`.